# Force PHP to wait for database action to complete before proceeding

Tags: php, redirect, pdo

Given some code like this...

```
$rs = $dbh->prepare("insert some stuff into the database ?");
$rs->Execute(array($somevalues));
header("Location: http://somewebpage.com");
exit;
```

Is there a way to force PHP to wait for the database to be updated before it processes the 'header' portion of the code?

I have a page that updates data.  I want to return to a 'fresh' page so that users can refresh it without the browser prompting to re-submit data.  The problem is, the redirect and page load is too quick.  It loads data from the database before the previous database operation has completed,  so it looks like the update didn't happen on the reloaded page.   I could add a manual delay but that's too crude.  I want the php code to simply wait until the database is updated before it does anything else.

**Edit - 04Dec11:**  It appears to have been a simple browser cacheing issue. I've added `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` to the top of the page and it now works as expected.

Comment: Not posting it as an answer because I'm not sure if this is a smart thing to do, but you could perform a while loop that runs until the database entry you just added exists.

Comment: Same for me, not sure whether that's working, but doesn't `$rs` return `true` when finished ?

Comment: It can't be, what db you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's just browser cache ;)

Comment: Didn't think of this, but the more I do, the more I think it's what's going on here.  Even though it's a PHP dynamically generated page, it could be that the browser is cheekily reloading its cached copy.  I'll add some no-cache to the php code and see if that helps.

Comment: Added "header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");" at the top of my page.  Problem solved :)

Comment: Best of all you disable cache when developing. Pure CSS and HTML is even more "stable" - meaning hard to reload sometimes. That saves a lot of headache ;)

Answer (score 9):

PHP is not asynchronous, so all operations will be blocking. Including SQL queries. Something else must be happening here.

Comment: That 'something else' appears to have been browser cacheing, as suggested by djot.  I've added some code to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible replication issue, that's if you are using a master->slave setup?