# How to make a DB query happen before text appears on page

Tags: php

I hope I don't confuse anyone with my title. Let me show you my codes first then explain what I would like to do.

**HERE is the main EXPLORE PAGE**

```
<?php

$ingame = "*";
require 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/modzoideditables.php';
include 'includes/zoideditables.php';
include 'includes/offdefvalues.php';
$move = 1;
?>
<center>
Choose Your Destination Below
<BR><BR><a href="/gonorth.php">NORTH</a> <BR>
<a href="/goeast.php">EAST</a><BR>
<a href="/gosouth.php">SOUTH</a><BR>
<a href="/gowest.php">WEST</a><BR>
</center>

<BR><BR><center>You are Currently located at <?=$user['uCord1']?>,<?=$user['uCord2']?></center>
 <?
require 'includes/footer.php';

?>
```

HERE IS NORTH PAGE

```
<?php

$ingame = "*";
require 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/modzoideditables.php';
include 'includes/zoideditables.php';
include 'includes/offdefvalues.php';
$move = 1;
 $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uCord2=uCord2+$move WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );
?>
<center>
Choose Your Destination Below
<BR><BR><a href="/gonorth.php">NORTH</a> <BR>
<a href="/goeast.php">EAST</a><BR>
<a href="/gosouth.php">SOUTH</a><BR>
<a href="/gowest.php">WEST</a><BR>
</center>

<BR><BR><center>You are Currently located at <?=$user['uCord1']?>,<?=$user['uCord2']?></center>
 <?
require 'includes/footer.php';

?>
```

**HERE is EAST PAGE**

```
<?php

$ingame = "*";
require 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/modzoideditables.php';
include 'includes/zoideditables.php';
include 'includes/offdefvalues.php';
$move = 1;
 $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uCord1=uCord1+$move WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );
?>
<center>
Choose Your Destination Below
<BR><BR><a href="/gonorth.php">NORTH</a> <BR>
<a href="/goeast.php">EAST</a><BR>
<a href="/gosouth.php">SOUTH</a><BR>
<a href="/gowest.php">WEST</a><BR>
</center>

<BR><BR><center>You are Currently located at <?=$user['uCord1']?>,<?=$user['uCord2']?></center>
 <?
require 'includes/footer.php';

?>
```

**SOUTH PAGE**

```
<?php

$ingame = "*";
require 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/modzoideditables.php';
include 'includes/zoideditables.php';
include 'includes/offdefvalues.php';
$move = 1;
 $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uCord2=uCord2-$move WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );
?>
<center>
Choose Your Destination Below
<BR><BR><a href="/gonorth.php">NORTH</a> <BR>
<a href="/goeast.php">EAST</a><BR>
<a href="/gosouth.php">SOUTH</a><BR>
<a href="/gowest.php">WEST</a><BR>
</center>

<BR><BR><center>You are Currently located at <?=$user['uCord1']?>,<?=$user['uCord2']?></center>
 <?
require 'includes/footer.php';

?>
```

**WEST page**

```
<?php

$ingame = "*";
require 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/modzoideditables.php';
include 'includes/zoideditables.php';
include 'includes/offdefvalues.php';
$move = 1;
$db->query( "UPDATE users SET uCord1=uCord1-$move WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );
?>
<center>
Choose Your Destination Below
<BR><BR><a href="/gonorth.php">NORTH</a> <BR>
<a href="/goeast.php">EAST</a><BR>
<a href="/gosouth.php">SOUTH</a><BR>
<a href="/gowest.php">WEST</a><BR>
</center>

<BR><BR><center>You are Currently located at <?=$user['uCord1']?>,<?=$user['uCord2']?></center>
 <?
require 'includes/footer.php';

?>
```

As you can see very simple and nothing really going on here. Everything is working the way I want it to except on thing. When it says

```
"You are Currently located at <?=$user['uCord1']?>,<?=$user['uCord2']?>"
```

its not showing the current DB Value of user, instead its showing the prior value.
so if they were to go north again. The next page would show their previous coordinates and not current.

Any quick fixes to this issue. Basically I want to have the DB query happen before any text can be shown without using any extra pages.

Comment: It's hard to say, since you don't show us where/how `$user` gets set.  Sounds to me like you just need to make that query second.  Also, be careful.  You are probably open to SQL injection attacks.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem.

Comment: PDO query are not asynchronous, maybe it's a caching issue? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367590/force-php-to-wait-for-database-action-to-complete-before-proceeding)

Comment: Please cease using the `<center>` immediately.

Comment: which require/include file contains your select query? im thinking your database values are being selected before they are updated, hense the old values still remain

Comment: @LiamAllan thats exactly what it was. I figured it out, thank you